# placeholder for <h:selectOneMenu>

Tags: css, jsf, facelets, placeholder

I successfully done using **placeholder**  in inputText but i tried this in selectOneMenu can't able to get . instead of martial status in selectOneMenu i want to use placeholder

or atleast i want to change martial status color

```
<h:selectOneMenu  value="">
<f:selectItem  itemValue="0" itemLabel="Marital status"/>
<f:selectItem itemValue="1" itemLabel="Single"/>
<f:selectItem itemValue="2" itemLabel="married"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Please elaborate a bit on the question and show us some code. See also http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you right

*JSF 1*

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Something" itemValue="#{null}" />
```

*JSF 2*

```
<f:selectItem itemValue="Select Something" noSelectionOption="true" />
```

Comment: actually i want martial status to be a grey color rest of the things black colour..i tried ur code not working..

Comment: try adding `itemDisabled="true"` to the `<f:selectItem `

Comment: i dont want to disable the itemLlabel.i want to change the grey colour for particular label

Comment: didn't you want to have a gray place holder ?