# Place holder for <h:selectMenu> with <f:selectItems>

Tags: html, jsf-2, xhtml, select-menu

All I want is to give a placeholder for the selectMenu. I am using select items for getting the values in the menu.

```
<h:selectManyMenu required="true" class="choose-group chosen-select"  value="#{sentMessage.selectedUserGroups}" >
                        <f:selectItems value="#{sentMessage.userGroups}" />

                    </h:selectManyMenu>
```

Currently its showing 'Select Some Options', but what I needed is 'Choose User Groups'.

I tried using this [placeholder for <h:selectOneMenu>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172775/placeholder-for-hselectonemenu)
But still no hope.

Comment: What do you mean "no hope"? I don't see `noSelectionOption` anywhere here, so what exactly have you tried?

Comment: i tried that too still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<h:selectManyMenu required="true" class="choose-group chosen-select"  
     value="#{sentMessage.selectedUserGroups}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose User Groups" noSelectionOption="true" itemValue="#{null}" />
    <f:selectItems value="#{sentMessage.userGroups}" />
</h:selectManyMenu>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to produce the html equivalent of:

```
<option value selected="selected" disabled="disabled">Choose User Groups</option>
```

To do that, you need to specify the option as disabled:

```
<h:selectManyMenu required="true" value="#{sentMessage.selectedUserGroups}">
  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose User Groups" noSelectionOption="true" itemDisabled="true" />
  <f:selectItems value="#{sentMessage.userGroups}" />
</h:selectManyMenu>
```

Note that the "noSelectionOption" attribute has no affect on the html output, but instead prevents selection of that value on the backend when a value is required, in which case the user will get a FacesMessage.